# keyboard layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, svg

I need a library|package for creating keyboard layout.
Is any example or package for them?

Now exist many form: japanese are different than normal, exist some smalest keyboard for example 80 keys 60%. Enter ANSI and UK, half keys in UMPC or palmtop, and long shift and space, some blinking indicators CAPS, ins etc, functionality or multimedia keys and rotor|potenciometer for volume control.

Some keys have 3 char not only 2

[image]

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44581/

Comment: No this is only how creating keys, I need layout. great to modyfy layout, put or not number sections, set language etc. Meybe exist this package. I dont know. I ask for half keys, how produce it, how fit heys to layout. Layout are more complicatet than key, look https://config.qmk.fm/ how create circle keys = rotor|potenciometer? https://community.popcorncomputer.com/t/pocket-p-c-keyboard-layout/204/5 https://ultimatehackingkeyboard.com/

Comment: enter keys https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key#/media/File:Enter.png not rectangle ; look at tab key https://www.pine64.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/psion-series-5-keyboard-layout-large-image.gif different size, sometimes arrows are outside and different layout

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: TikZ is a good library for drawing things; see http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/. Build your own objects is the fastest way. A good example will be the oscillocope (http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/textronics-oscilloscope/) so you can see layout arrangement and items. And (http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/seven-segment-display/) for drawing the segments. What calculator do you want to draw?