# Proper horizontal alignment of text in tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I am using XeTeX and tikz to generate a cheat sheet for an unusual keyboard layout (gb + apl).
Inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44581/creating-keyboard-layout-diagrams), I set up a command to quickly associate the symbols that are bound to each key:

```
\tikzstyle{abstract}=[
    rectangle,
    draw=black,
    rounded corners,
    fill=gray!20,
    drop shadow,
    text=black]

\newcommand{\mykey}[4]{%
\resizebox{1.25cm}{1.25cm}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]
{\textbf{\footnotesize{#2} \hfill \footnotesize{#4}} \nodepart{second}\textbf{\footnotesize{#1} \hfill \footnotesize{#3}}};%
\end{tikzpicture}}}
```

Then I use this command to generate the whole keyboard, as follows:

```
\begin{document}
\mykey{a}{A}{⍺}{⍶}
\mykey{s}{S}{⌈}{}
% etc
\end{document}
```

I am quite pleased with the result:
[image: gb-apl keyboard layout]

But there are a couple of small details that I do not really like:

- I would like the two columns within each key to be further apart.
- I would like the keys with three symbols to have the top row aligned to the left (for example, in the key with the Y, the capital Y should be aligned with the lowercase y).

Edit: also, I am not sure that the call to `\resizebox` is the best option to achieve equal square boxes.

Thanks in advance for the help!

In case somebody is interested, I'm using the font APL333 which I downloaded [here](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Fonts)

The full code for generating the page above is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{APL333}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows}

\tikzstyle{abstract}=[
    rectangle,
    draw=black,
    rounded corners,
    fill=gray!20,
    drop shadow,
    text=black]

\newcommand{\mykey}[4]{%
\resizebox{1.25cm}{1.25cm}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]
{\textbf{\footnotesize{#2} \hfill \footnotesize{#4}} \nodepart{second}\textbf{\footnotesize{#1} \hfill \footnotesize{#3}}};%
\end{tikzpicture}}}


\begin{document}

\mykey{`}{¬}{⋄}{⌺}
\mykey{1}{!}{¨}{⌶}
\mykey{2}{"}{¯}{⍫}
\mykey{3}{£}{<}{⍒}
\mykey{4}{\$}{≤}{⍋}
\mykey{5}{\%}{=}{⌽}
\mykey{6}{\textasciicircum}{≥}{⍉}
\mykey{7}{\&}{>}{⊖}
\mykey{8}{*}{≠}{⍟}
\mykey{9}{(}{∨}{⍱}
\mykey{0}{)}{∧}{⍲}
\mykey{-}{\_}{×}{ }
\mykey{=}{+}{÷}{⌹}

\mykey{q}{Q}{?}{⍰}
\mykey{w}{W}{⍵}{⍹}
\mykey{e}{E}{∊}{⍷}
\mykey{r}{R}{⍴}{⌾}
\mykey{t}{T}{\textasciitilde}{⍨}
\mykey{y}{Y}{↑}{}
\mykey{u}{U}{↓}{}
\mykey{i}{I}{⍳}{⍸}
\mykey{o}{O}{○}{⍥}
\mykey{p}{P}{*}{⍣}
\mykey{[}{\{}{←}{⍞}
\mykey{]}{\}}{→}{⍬}

\mykey{a}{A}{⍺}{⍶}
\mykey{s}{S}{⌈}{}
\mykey{d}{D}{⌊}{}
\mykey{f}{F}{\_}{}
\mykey{g}{G}{∇}{⍢}
\mykey{h}{H}{∆}{}
\mykey{j}{J}{∘}{⍤}
\mykey{k}{K}{'}{⌸}
\mykey{l}{L}{⎕}{⌷}
\mykey{;}{:}{⍎}{≡}
\mykey{'}{@}{⍕}{≢}
\mykey{\#}{\textasciitilde}{⊢}{⊣}

\mykey{\textbackslash}{|}{⊢}{⊣}
\mykey{z}{Z}{⊂}{⊆}
\mykey{x}{X}{⊃}{}
\mykey{c}{C}{∩}{}
\mykey{v}{V}{∪}{}
\mykey{b}{B}{⊥}{⍭}
\mykey{n}{N}{⊤}{⍡}
\mykey{m}{M}{|}{∥}
\mykey{,}{<}{⍝}{⍪}
\mykey{.}{>}{⍀}{⍙}
\mykey{/}{?}{⌿}{⍠}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `matrix` would be useful here, see example in the code below.

The problem with using `\resizebox` like that is that everything will be scaled by slightly different amounts, if the sizes of the symbols are slightly different. So not a good idea here I think. I'd probably just set the `text width`/`height`/`depth` to a large enough values.

Compared to the original answer, I used a different `ampersand replacement` (since `\&` was one of the symbols in the keys), and wrapped each matrix entry in `{}`.

[image: output of below code]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{APL333}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{abstract/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw=black,
    rounded corners,
    fill=gray!20,
    drop shadow,
    text=black}
}
    
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shapes.multipart, matrix}
\newcommand{\mykey}[4]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
  abstract,
  matrix of nodes,
  column sep=3pt, % <-- modify this to change the column spacing
  nodes={
    font=\footnotesize\bfseries,
    anchor=base,
    text width=1.1em, text depth=0.6ex, text height=1.7ex, % these may need fine tuning
    align=center
  },
  name=m,
  ampersand replacement=\NewCol,
  inner sep=0,
]
{
 {#2}  \NewCol {#4}  \\
 {#1}  \NewCol {#3} \\
 };
 
\draw [very thin] (m.east) -- (m.west);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\mykey{`}{¬}{⋄}{⌺}
\mykey{1}{!}{¨}{⌶}
\mykey{2}{"}{¯}{⍫}
\mykey{3}{£}{<}{⍒}
\mykey{4}{\$}{≤}{⍋}
\mykey{5}{\%}{=}{⌽}
\mykey{6}{\textasciicircum}{≥}{⍉}
\mykey{7}{\&}{>}{⊖}
\mykey{8}{*}{≠}{⍟}
\mykey{9}{(}{∨}{⍱}
\mykey{0}{)}{∧}{⍲}
\mykey{-}{\_}{×}{ }
\mykey{=}{+}{÷}{⌹}

\mykey{q}{Q}{?}{⍰}
\mykey{w}{W}{⍵}{⍹}
\mykey{e}{E}{∊}{⍷}
\mykey{r}{R}{⍴}{⌾}
\mykey{t}{T}{\textasciitilde}{⍨}
\mykey{y}{Y}{↑}{}
\mykey{u}{U}{↓}{}
\mykey{i}{I}{⍳}{⍸}
\mykey{o}{O}{○}{⍥}
\mykey{p}{P}{*}{⍣}
\mykey{[}{\{}{←}{⍞}
\mykey{]}{\}}{→}{⍬}

\mykey{a}{A}{⍺}{⍶}
\mykey{s}{S}{⌈}{}
\mykey{d}{D}{⌊}{}
\mykey{f}{F}{\_}{}
\mykey{g}{G}{∇}{⍢}
\mykey{h}{H}{∆}{}
\mykey{j}{J}{∘}{⍤}
\mykey{k}{K}{'}{⌸}
\mykey{l}{L}{⎕}{⌷}
\mykey{;}{:}{⍎}{≡}
\mykey{'}{@}{⍕}{≢}
\mykey{\#}{\textasciitilde}{⊢}{⊣}

\mykey{\textbackslash}{|}{⊢}{⊣}
\mykey{z}{Z}{⊂}{⊆}
\mykey{x}{X}{⊃}{}
\mykey{c}{C}{∩}{}
\mykey{v}{V}{∪}{}
\mykey{b}{B}{⊥}{⍭}
\mykey{n}{N}{⊤}{⍡}
\mykey{m}{M}{|}{∥}
\mykey{,}{<}{⍝}{⍪}
\mykey{.}{>}{⍀}{⍙}
\mykey{/}{?}{⌿}{⍠}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am receiving an error when I try to run xelatex with your definition of `\mykey`: ```! Argument of \pgfmatrixendrow@skip has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.83 \mykey{[}{\{}{←}{⍞}
                        
? 
Runaway argument?
 \& ← \\ 
! Paragraph ended before \pgfmatrixendrow@skip was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.83 \mykey{[}{\{}{←}{⍞}```

Comment: @J.D. Don't know why that happens, if you can add a complete example to your question, with font setup etc, I can at least test.

Comment: Sure! I just edited the page with my old code for `\mykey`. I'm afraid that might require that you install the font I linked in my question.

Comment: Since one of your key contain "\&" try `ampersand replacement=\1` instead of `ampersand replacement=\&`.

Comment: @vipa Thanks,  I realized the same. Had to wrap each cell in `{}` in addition though.

Comment: @J.D. Try the updated code.

Comment: Brilliant! It looks really great, thanks!